# Allows multiple questions to be opened on FAQ Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

**I want to modify my code where it allows me to open multiple questions at once, because in this code it only opens one. when I opened another question, the previous one closes.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./faq.css";

function Faq() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const toggle = (id) => {
    if (selected === id) {
      return setSelected(null);
    }

    setSelected(id);
  };



  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
      <div className="questions">
        {Questions.map((question) => (
          <div key={question.id}>
            <h4>
              {question.title}
              <button onClick={() => toggle(question.id)}>
                {selected === question.id ? "X" : "+"}
              </button>
            </h4>
            <p
              className={selected === question.id ? "question-info" : "hidden"}
            >
              {question.info}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Faq;
```

**Here is my code and I can't solve this problem**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining one selected, maintain multiple selected indices in an array like:

```js
export function Faq(props) {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
    {
      id:0,
      title:"hey",
      info:"hey"
    },
    {
      id:1,
      title:"hello",
      info:"hello"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title:"heyyyy",
      info:"heyyyy"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      title:"ne",
      info:"ne"
    }
  ]);

  const toggle = (id) => {
    if (selected.includes(id)) {
      const index = selected.indexOf(id);
      selected.splice(index,1);
    }else{
      selected.push(id);
    }
    setSelected([...selected]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
      <div className="questions">
        {questions.map((question) => (
          <div key={question.id}>
            <h4>
              {question.title}
              <button onClick={() => toggle(question.id)}>
                {selected.includes(question.id) ? "X" : "+"}
              </button>
            </h4>
            <p
              className={selected.includes(question.id) ? "question-info" : "hidden"}
            >
              {question.info}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```